# Pandas summation for a list inside of a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

this is my first post in Stackoverflow. I was just coding a dice problem in my Statistics book and here is my code.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

die1, die2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

samplespace = list(product(die1, die2))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample Space' : samplespace}
                  )
df2
```

Output is

```
Sample Space
0   (1, 1)
1   (1, 2)
2   (1, 3)
3   (1, 4)
4   (1, 5)
5   (1, 6)
6   (2, 1)
7   (2, 2)
8   (2, 3)
9   (2, 4)
10  (2, 5)
11  (2, 6)
12  (3, 1)
13  (3, 2)
14  (3, 3)
15  (3, 4)
16  (3, 5)
17  (3, 6)
18  (4, 1)
19  (4, 2)
20  (4, 3)
21  (4, 4)
22  (4, 5)
23  (4, 6)
24  (5, 1)
25  (5, 2)
26  (5, 3)
27  (5, 4)
28  (5, 5)
29  (5, 6)
30  (6, 1)
31  (6, 2)
32  (6, 3)
33  (6, 4)
34  (6, 5)
35  (6, 6)
```

I want to add each element like

(1,1) which is 2

and create a new variable just next to Sample Space and put the each summation.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) `sum` to each tuple:

```
df2['Sum Sample Space'] = df2['Sample Space'].apply(sum)
```

Or with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas-series-sum):

```
df2['Sum Sample Space'] = df2['Sample Space'].explode().sum(level=0)
```

`df2.head(15)`:

```
   Sample Space  Sum Sample Space
0        (1, 1)                 2
1        (1, 2)                 3
2        (1, 3)                 4
3        (1, 4)                 5
4        (1, 5)                 6
5        (1, 6)                 7
6        (2, 1)                 3
7        (2, 2)                 4
8        (2, 3)                 5
9        (2, 4)                 6
10       (2, 5)                 7
11       (2, 6)                 8
12       (3, 1)                 4
13       (3, 2)                 5
14       (3, 3)                 6
```

Comment: It worked thanks but I want to have a question regarding your answer. df2['Sum Sample Space'] = df2['Sample Space'].apply(sum) why normal .sum() doesn't work?

Comment: `Sum()` does cell + cell + cell. Right? So `pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).sum()` is `6`. What does `(1,1) + (1,2)` in python give? (`pd.Series([(1, 1), (1, 2)]).sum()`) `(1, 1, 1, 2)`. Whereas `apply` sum performs the `sum` operation on each _cell_ in the column/`Series`. Which is like `pd.Series([sum((1, 1)), sum((1, 2))])` which makes `pd.Series([2,3])` which is the expected result.